# Ember returning undefined for url parameter depending on the name of the parameter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm experiencing some weird behavior with a route parameter in Ember. It works depending on what the name of the route parameter is.

I have a router that looks like this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('movies', { path: '/movies/:release_date' });
});
```

and a route that looks like this

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
     console.log('HI ' + Ember.keys(params) + ', ' + params.release_date);
     return this.store.findAll('movie', params.release_date);
  }
});
```

When I visit the route `/movies/foo` I see this in the console

```
HI release_date, undefined
```

However, if I change the param to almost anything other than `release_date`, it works as expected (i.e., change it in both the definition in the router and in the route object itself).  Examples:

```
HI rel_date, foo
HI release_d, foo
```

Why does this happen?  Is there any way to make it work with `release_date` as the parameter?

Comment: It would be interesting to see if this only happens in the Ember version that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rm -rf tmp/
```

And restart your server.

It is more likely to be a typo in your app than an Ember.js problem.

This works: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pefudesaya/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I wonder if it could be considered a bug in embercli that it would keep something in cache that would totally break stuff like that.  Almost impossible to reproduce, though :/